# How to include sample helloworld jsp file in the virtual box linux in hadoop?

Tags: linux, jsp, hadoop, hdfs

I need to include my sample jsp file in hadoop. And display the output in the localhost of hadoop in the webbrowser. I couldn't have the idea of where i need to include the jsp file and what is the command for the execution of the file  becuase, I am new to this technology can any one help me , how to include and execute the jsp file.

Comment: Your question does not make sense clearly. But as far as I understood, you want to load it to HDFS. $> bin/hadoop fs -put *.jsp to load it into HDFS.

Comment: hi aditya thanks for the quick reply can you please sent me the steps for execution to display my file in the browser

Comment: may be you can try, localhost:50057  in your browser. Put hostname instead of localhost.

Comment: hi aditya thanks again, i need to move my jsp in hadoop , how can i do can you explain me a bit. And the steps for execution

Comment: Totaly depends on which version of hadoop you are using. Let us consider you are using Yarn 2.0, so these links might help you. http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2013/06/Apache.Hadoop.YARN_.Sample.pdf  &   http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/install-hadoop-2-0-1-yarn-nextgen/

Comment: Hi Aditya, i already installed hortonsworks in my system and i got basic links , what is my requirement is i need to create a sample jsp program and display that custom jsp file out put in my browser that steps only i need can you please

Comment: Oh. what you want is web service. You have to install map reduce plugin in eclipse & write java programs, map reduce as back-end & jsp as front end. there are lot of api's are also available, amazon, yahoo. Search for it.

Comment: Just i need to execute helloworld.jsp in hortonworks environment. Please provide me the steps to run that program using through browser with proper url. hence what are all the configurations i need to do in hortonworks.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is not capable of running your jsp pages. 
I recommend you install tomcat instead.

Update:
You are insistingly trying to put a screw into a wall with a hammer. If you want to serve a JSP page use jetty or tomcat, don't use hadoop. Hadoop does have jsp pages it can a serve, but these are ONLY for serving the hadoop specific pages. The hadoop toolset uses jetty for that purpose. As said repeatedly by many others:
Hadoop is not capable of running your jsp pages.

Comment: Hi Niels , then how can execute the jsp file in hadoop, can you please explaing a bit with steps

Comment: with hadoop i installed hortonworks which contain default servers and databases

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop does have an in-built jetty to run jsp for its job status. Is not that you cannot run your own jsp but for that you need to explore Hadoop source code

Comment: yes Abhishek , I am having the jetty built in my hadoop, but i don't have the idea where i need to place my jsp file and how to run that file. What is the command for executing that file  these are things i need to know can you explain me bit

Answer (score 0):

ya, use Apache Tomcat to run jsp pages. because it has built in jsp/servlet parser...

Comment: how can we execute the jsp file in hadoop pyare that's is my question and which location i need to place my jsp in hadoop. And what is the command to execute the file and how can i see my output in browser

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply. 
These tutorial will surely help out what you want.
[Hortonworks Tutorial](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/hello-world-an-introduction-to-hadoop-hcatalog-hive-and-pig/).

Also this [one](http://hortonworks.com/tutorials/)

Comment: hi Aditya , this one i already found,but i need steps to run my helloworld jsp file in browser

Comment: Hi Bala. It's not possible to define all the steps here. You can refer that tutorial & can go one by one. Also it is necessary to have a basic Java language knowledge, so that you will be able to write down map reduce programs & create web service that would run your program on Browsers. It should be like, you have a jsp file that takes some input file, say a .pig file that is with a SQL Query, & it loads the file, perform the Query Execution & will again display the result to you in a jsp file in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** run your own JSP files via Hadoop. Its explained as

`Apache Hadoop is an open-source software framework for storage and large scale processing of data-sets on clusters of commodity hardware`

To serve JSP files, you will need a JSP/Servlet container , most likely [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). Once you have that configured in your virtual machine, simple copy paste your project into the *webapps* folder of tomcat and it will serve the JSP.